# Установка границ для блока

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, asp.net-mvc

Осваиваю bootstrap и столкнулся с проблемой. Мне нужно для моих блоков (левый,правый,нижний) установить видимые границы, чтобы было четкое разделение между блоками. Как мне нужно это сделать, пробовал через border-color в css, не получается. Я не совсем понимаю,как это сделать.

```
<div class="jumbotron">
<h1>Стеганографічний додаток</h1>
        <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4 col-md-push-7">
                    <h3>Правый блок</h3>
                    <p>................</p>
                </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-md-pull-3">
                <h3>Левый блок</h3>
                <p>................</p>
            </div>
        </div>
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-push-4">
        <h3>Нижний блок</h3>
        <p>................</p>
    </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Кроме `border-color`, нужно еще задавать `border-width` - толщину линий границы.

Answer (score 1):

можно так в css попробовать
border:solid red 1px

Comment: Я так и делал, но все равно никаких изменений. Правда я это описываю для класса row. Возможно, мне нужно это написать для другого diva?

Answer (score 1):

```
h3 {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background: red;
}
```

Comment: кто тебя постоянно минусует ? я если вижу такое плюсую - вот как щас например

Comment: Попробовал, ничего не изменилось(

Comment: проверь файл со стилями вообще подключен? не знаю кто минусует, наверное ответы не правильные)

Comment: Да, немного выше он у меня подключатеся

Answer (score 0):

Для bootstrap 4 добавляем все границы и убираем верхнюю:

```
class="border border-primary border-top-0"
```

http://bootstrap-4.ru/docs/4.1/utilities/borders
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/borders
https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_utilities.asp